# How do I save a question for offline viewing?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed

This sounds like a question that should have been asked a lot of times all around SE, but I haven't found it. Since I'm trying to save a page from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2309/problem-with-nonlinearmodelfit) I thought I'd start by asking this here.

There are some problems with File -> Save As ... in Firefox. For example, the hidden comments that become visible when you click "add / show # more comments" are not saved. Also, the page loses a lot of its formatting and becomes harder to read. I tried using the "mobile" version of the site, but these problems remain.

Is there a printer-friendly version of the site? How do I access it? What's the best way to save `scicomp` pages?

(I tagged this question `feature-request` because I don't think the "printer-friendly" functionality or an equivalent is present in the site. Maybe I just haven't found it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the [StackPrinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) work for you?

Note: found this from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36709/printer-friendly-button) by searching on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/, which is apparently where we go for questions that have broad applicability across all of the StackExchange sites.